# Bounteous Beauty (A Haiku)

Tags: riddle, word, poetry, acrostic

Since my riddles typically rhyme, I wanted to try my hand at another form of poetry. I hope you enjoy.

> Strong scents give me life
> Pleasing to the eye, I give
> Each day a fresh breath
>
> Carefully managed
> I'll lead you to a new friend
> A beauty blossomed
>
> Look and be amazed
> So fleeting, symbol immortal
> Kaleidoscopic

What am I?

Hint:

> You see me each day
> If not you live a sad life
> Go out and find me.

Comment: This riddle is indeed special. DVL8 $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you

> Flowers?

Strong scents give me life

> Flowers usually smell nice (some of them have other strong smells).

Pleasing to the eye, I give

> They are pleasing to the eye.

Each day a fresh breath

> Giving somebody flowers is a nice way to start their day.

Carefully managed

> If you take care of them...

I'll lead you to a new friend

> They might be pollinated to create more flowers.

A beauty blossomed

> Flowers are beautiful and blossom.

Look and be amazed

> Lots of flower festivals.

So fleeting, symbol immortal

> Flowers are symbols for a lot of things, they are fleeting and die every year.

Kaleidoscopic

> They come in a rainbow of colours.

The secret hint

> Is SPECIAL, which would be the kind of person I’d give flowers to.

The other hint:

> You see me each day 
>  **People see flowers every day.** 
>  If not you live a sad life 
>  **Because you’re always inside with no plants.** 
>  Go out and find me. 
>  **Flowers are outside.**

Comment: This is what I was looking for, good job!

Comment: Nice answer if this didn't get accepted I was going to answer the woods for the each day a fresh breath to be trees that produce oxygen and then include plants for the others :p.

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> Wheat or Cereal Grains?

Strong scents give me life 
Pleasing to the eye, I give 
Each day a fresh breath

> Wheat fields are photogenic and cereal gives each day a new start (ie. breakfast).

Carefully managed 
I'll lead you to a new friend 
A beauty blossomed

> Carefully managed, you can grow fields of wheat and use the grains for anything.

Look and be amazed 
So fleeting, symbol immortal 
Kaleidoscopic

> Wheat only lasts less than a year; but it is an immortal symbol of farming.

This is a stretch and a half, but

> Your acrostic of SPECIAL K (SPECIAL S[pace] K) kinda got me hooked.

Comment: I see you took the acrostic literally. A very interesting answer, but not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Another guess

> Rainbow

Strong scents give me life
Pleasing to the eye, I give
Each day a fresh breath

> Umm they are pretty.

Carefully managed
I'll lead you to a new friend

> At the end of the rainbow!

A beauty blossomed

> They are amazing to look at.

Look and be amazed
So fleeting, symbol immortal

> God used a rainbow to say no more floods across the earth.

Kaleidoscope

> If you type in synonyms for kaleidoscope you get rainbow!

Comment: I'm not sure the first line fits with this answer. But this is pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

Are you a

> Strawberry

Strong scents give me life

> They are sweet.

Pleasing to the eye, I give

> Bright and red.

Each day a fresh breath

> Fresh strawberries are awesome.

Carefully managed

> Grown in a farm.

I'll lead you to a new friend
A beauty blossomed

> More fruit, maybe other forms of strawberries(jam, ice cream)?

Look and be amazed
So fleeting, symbol immortal
Kaleidoscopic

> They are bright.

Acrositc

> They are in special K.

Comment: A great answer, but truth be told, the K for the acrostic isn't actually part of it. I needed an extra line to make the third haiku. I hope that helps.